# Career effect of embargo on doctoral dissertation

Tags: graduate-school

I have a question about how my dissertation embargo period would affect my future work, so please help and share your ideas. I will appreciate any thoughts here.

My PhD degree is high performance computation. I finished my PhD degree oral defense last week, and I am about to submit my final dissertation to the university. As for the dissertation embargo period, my university offers 3 options: (1) release immediately; (2) hold 2 or 5 yrs; (3) indefinite hold.

I personally want to embargo my dissertation for 5 years for publication reasons, but my PhD advisor recommended me for choosing indefinite hold first. He said because we are trying to apply for a patent which may take a really long time, and he also mentioned that some chapters are cooperated with industry partners and they don't want them to be released.

Most of my chapters have been published in peer-reviewed journals, which means even if my dissertation is under embargo, people can still know what my Ph.D. research is about.

But I still have a question: If I choose to embargo my dissertation indefinitely, will this affect my future career in a bad way?

Comment: Side question: do you habe any contracts etc with the industry partners?

Comment: Not really..... I just don't know if this indefinite hold would affect me or not.

Comment: I have no idea if anyone ever actually read my thesis outside of my committee. I know my parents didn’t. It really isn’t a problem if you have the papers out or in process of going out.

Comment: If you don't understand from the university and your advisor what an indefinite hold would mean, you'd better ask them.

Comment: Nobody is ever going to read your dissertation. Nobody is ever even going to look for it. Just do whatever your advisor recommends; they're probably overthinking it but it will not ever matter for you so just go with it.

Comment: I consider it an obligation for the university to make the thesis publicly available in a reasonable period of time.  For the university to impose an indefinite hold is unethical.  The student has no responsibilities to make their thesis publicly available, so they are free to choose the option that benefits the student.

Comment: Most parts of my dissertation have been published as journal papers, so reading them is equal to read my dissertation. But I still want to share it. Our university just offered this indefinite hold option for us and my advisor wanted me to choose it. I know some students who are funded by the government, their dissertations are restricted.

Answer (score 6):

I do not see that embargoing your dissertation will have any consequences for your career. Until recently, theses and dissertations only existed in hard copy: at least in the sciences, people expect to read your papers and not your thesis. In all likelihood, nobody will ever notice that you've embargoed it.

In any case, placing an embargo on the thesis just prevents *the university library* from distributing it. There is nothing to stop *you* sharing a copy with someone (e.g. a potential postdoc supervisor) if you wish to do so.

Comment: So even if it is under embargo, it is OK to share it if it is from me, right? It is not a violation of copyright?

Comment: The copyright is the author's, regardless. The embargo is simply about whether Joe Public can access a copy through the library. It is fine to share it yourself (though it would be polite to discuss this with your supervisor/anyone else who has an interest in the work before doing so).

Comment: If the embargo is for possible future patenting it would be defeated if you were allowed to distribute it your self without the recipients signing NDAs. However the patent reason for the embargo doesn’t hold water if all of the inventions disclosed in the thesis are already disclosed in published papers.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I guess you're always *allowed* to - it just isn't always a good idea.

Comment: My point is if the OP doesn’t understand the reason for the embargo they might accidentally defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new concept to me, but general principles would suggest that you keep as flexible as possible. If a, say, five year embargo really restricts you to that, then it seems a poor option. You can't read the future and it is known to hide secrets we can't see.

Perhaps that is the intention of your advisor in suggesting an indefinite hold. Assuming, of course, that you can submit it as you choose, when you choose.

The "really long time" might become a "really short time" if conditions change.

Another principle is to consider your own interests rather than being overly influenced by the interests of your partners. It is good if they align, but when and where they don't, take care.

Comment: I have nothing to hide. My advisor just said this option can be changed any time in the future if everyone is comfortable.But most of my chapters are published as journal papers (5 now), so holding it forever maybe not matter to me.